# Vue3 Select/Options with v-for not displaying options from graphql query results

Tags: javascript, select, vuejs3

Hours of struggling with this and haven't found a solution...

This modal should pull a group of items via an graphql API query from DDB and displays one of the values from the items in a dropdown list. I cannot get the dropdown list to populate no matter what I have tried.

Below, you can see the console.log statement which has no issues displaying the correct array of items in the console....but I can't figure out how to make the 'longname' value display in the dropdown. The dropdown only shows the static disabled text, but the items do not list at all.

```
<form>
  <h1 class="mb-12 text-3xl">Change School</h1>
  <div>
    <span class="font-normal">Current School:</span>
    <input class="border border-black-800 mb-4 ml-2 pl-2" type="text" 
              :placeholder=school.shortname /> 
  </div>
  <div>Change To:
    <select v-model="selectedSchool" class="border border-slate-400 pl-1 mb-4 w-80">
      <option disabled value="">Select school</option>
      <option v-for="item in schoolList" :key="item.id" :value="item.longname"> {{ item.longname }}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

```
<script>
import { Auth, Hub, API } from 'aws-amplify';
import { listSchools } from '../../graphql/queries';
    
export default {
  name: 'app',
  async created() {
    this.getAllSchools();
  },
  data() {
    return {
      schoolList: [], signedIn: false, user: {}, modalShow: true, newschool: '', 
      selectedSchool: ''
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async getAllSchools() {
      const schools = await API.graphql({
           query: listSchools
      });
      const schoolList = schools.data.listSchools.items;
      console.log(schoolList)
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: instead of assigning to `const schoolList`, which is a new variable scoped only to the `getAllSchools` method, you should assign the result of the graphql call to `this.schoolList`, which is the component data variable being used in your form

Comment: @yoduh I knew it was something so simple, just couldn't see it through the fog.  Your fix worked...thanks!